# Java compiler is failing to resolve for ojdb6-11.2.0.3 with mvn and pom.xml

Tags: java, oracle, maven, pom.xml

I have a servlet in STS3.7 and I am unable to get the compiler to find the ojdbc6.jar file?

I have run the following command:

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc6 -Dversion=11.2.0.3 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=lib\ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar -DgeneratePom=true
```

In my project root directory which contains the lib directory where the jar file is located.

[image]

The result of running this command can be seen in my .m2 directory:

[image]

This is the entry in my pom.xml file:

[image]

This is the issue my code:

[image]

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Here is the build path libraries:

[image]

Comment: Can u show us the details of Java build path Libraries?

Comment: did you try to maven update your project? also make a project>clean

Comment: So I am running STS3.7 and I don't see the maven update.  I have tried the clean.  I added the build path libraries.  The ojdbc.jar file is definitely not there.

Comment: Does it compile on the command-line? If so, it is probably Eclipse (well m2e) getting confused and you should Maven update the project (right-click, Maven > Update Project)